Why do the diodes make a huge difference in an RC sinewave generator circuit?
In the following LTspice simulation of a sine wave generator circuit, it cannot oscillate without D1 and D2, but as long as D1 and D2 are added, (1+R5/R6)=1.5 can also oscillate (as shown in the figure below.)
Doesn't the textbook say that the role of D1 and D2 is to provide non-linear amplitude stabilization? Why does it have such a big impact on the oscillation? I haven’t built the actual circuit yet so I'm not sure if this is the real situation.


What textbook are you referring to?  What are the traces on the graph?

That's a diode-stabilised Wien bridge oscillator (Older versions employ a lamp). Isn't the textbook you refer to enough to explain how the circuit works?

Try to increase the simulation time is see if the oscillation is dying out.

The overall gain should be "3".
It can't be with only the resistors.
When you add the diodes, you add a "resistor" which decreases with the amplitude of the signal.
So, at start, the gain is greater than needed, and than it falls until the "oscillation" condition is "just" met.
See the start of oscillation with 21 kOhm ... Saturated output.

Reduce a little this resistor and add 2 diodes ...

Here is an example (harmonic distortion) with a resistor paralleled with the diodes.
Very long simulation calculus.


Thanks. I editted the original graph, it shows Vout now. Textbook's main point is just like your reply.
Previously i think that the overall gain should be more than 3, so i would let A=1+R5/R6>3, and then put on diodes to decrease the amplitude of the signal.
But now you see in the above graph, A=(1+(R5+rd)/R6)=1.5+rd/R6, i am not sure here if A>3 or not. but the circuit still works. that's what confuses me most.

@ Antonio - I am surprised a bit about your negative feedback path. I think, the classical solution is to use two diodes in parallel to one of the two feedback resistors.

@ 谢一鸣 - I don`t think that it is sufficient to say "it works".......the main question is about the quality of the signal. Even without any diodes (or any other additional non-linear parts) the circuit can "work" with R5/R6>2. In this case: Hard limiting of the amplitudes.

@LvW you are right. To adjust "at best" feedback, we can add a resistor (value ?) in parallel with the two diodes (eventually series Zener backward) ... and adjust the R3 resistor for the "lowest" distortion.

@ Antonio - to find "optimum" values for the feedback resistors is not a simple task. It depends on (a) tolerance aspects and (b) distortion requirements and (c) desired amplitude values.

The problem with your circuit is that the dimensioning is wrong.

The oscillation condition requires that the closed-loop gain at the desired oscillation frequency is "3". Hence, the feedback resistor must be exactly twice the resistor between the "-"input and ground (R5/R6=2).

However, with respect to (a) parts tolerances and (b) safe start of oscillations the closed-loop gain Acl at t=0 should be a little bit larger than "3" (Acl=1+R5/R6>3).

More than that, when the oscillation builds up the amplitude increase should be limited before the supply rails are reached (hard limiting). This means: The resistor R5 must be automatically (slightly) reduced - therefore, two diodes are to be placed across the feedback resistor.

As a better solution (less distortions),


a) the resistor R5 is splitted up into two series resistors and only one of the two resistors gets the two diodes in parallel, or
b) the resistor R5 is selected as R5>R6 with an additional parallel path consisting of another (large) resistor in series with the two anti-parallel diodes.

Thanks, but why in my circuit, $Acl=1+\frac{R5}{R6}=1.5$ and it still oscillate?

My answer: Because for  small amplitudes the diodes present a dynamic resistance rd which can fulfill the oscillation condition R5+rd=2R6. However, the influence of rd is pretty strong - and this results in distortions.

I just further set R5 to 10 ohm in ltspice with all other variables unchanged, and it still worked..., I may build a real circuit to see for myself if that is the real case...
Thanks, I will post my observation to you.

@谢一鸣 ... and it still oscillate? try with other diode models and see if it oscillates. I'm sure it will not. And then change R5 to 20k or even higher, it'll start to oscillate.

I don`t think that a feedback resistor as low as 10 ohms in series with the diodes can produce a good sinusoidal signal of some volts.
